# Em uma aplicação de pequeno porte seria uma opção valida utilizar o 'quick.db' ou isso traria problemas futuros?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orientação-a-objetos

Estou programando uma API para uso em um aplicativo Windows de pequeno porte e estive com algumas duvidas na hora de realizar a implantação da API.
Na hora de escolher o banco de dados para utilizar em minha aplicação, encontrei problema em selecionar oque seria de fácil implementação, porem não deixasse a desejar na parte de desempenho.
Estava entre o 'quick.db' (Utiliza o better-sqlite3), Mongoose(MongoDB) ou partir para MySql / SqlServer.
Pela praticidade e simplicidade de implementação optei por utilizar o quick.db, porem, o mesmo não possui uma função de Models como o Mongoose por exemplo. Para sanar esse problema eu segui alguns tutorias e fiz a seguinte implementação:

Código do objeto Conta.

```
const db = require('quick.db');
const md5 = require('md5');

String.prototype.ReplaceAll = function (stringToFind, stringToReplace) {
    var temp = this;
    var index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
    while (index != -1) {
        temp = temp.replace(stringToFind, stringToReplace);
        index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
    }
    return temp;
};

var Conta = new Object ({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    token: "",
    avatar: "",
    findByEmail: async function (email) {
        let e = email.ReplaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase();
        let contas = await db.get(`arka.usuarios`);
        if (contas == null) return null;
        let jsonString = JSON.stringify(contas);
        let conta = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        for (var c in conta) {
            if (e === conta[c].email) {
                return conta[c];
            }
        }
        return null;
    },
    createAccount: async function (email, password, avatar = "") {
        let e = email.ReplaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase();
        if (await this.findByEmail(e) != null) return null;
        let p = password.ReplaceAll(" ", "").toLowerCase();
        let token = md5('arkatokengenerate' + e + p);
        let user = {
            "email":e,
            "password": p,
            "token": token,
            "avatar": avatar
        };
        await db.set(`arka.usuarios.${token}`, user);
        let ret = Object.create(Conta);
        ret.email = e;
        ret.password = p;
        ret.token = token;
        ret.avatar = avatar;
        console.log(ret);
        return ret;
    }
});

module.exports = Conta;
```

Exemplo de como estou utilizando o objeto

```
const Conta = require('../model/conta');

exports.createAccount = async function (req, res, next) {
    let json = req.body;
    if (!json) return res.status(400).send({status: 0, erro: "Envie os dados para realizar a requisição", data: []});
    if (!json.email) return res.status(400).send({status: 0, erro: "Informe o email para realizar a requisição", data: []});
    if (!json.password) return res.status(400).send({status: 0, erro: "Informe a senha para realizar a requisição", data: []});
    if (!json.rpassword) return res.status(400).send({status: 0, erro: "Repita a senha para realizar a requisição", data: []});
    let u = Object.create(Conta);
    u = await u.createAccount(json.email, json.password, json.avata != null ? json.avatar : "");
    res.status(200).send({status: 1, erro: "", data: [u]});
};
```

Esta implementação utilizando o banco de dados 'quick.db' com uma possível implementação de POO seria a melhor solução para possuir um sistema simples e eficiente ou futuramente poderei ter problemas de performance com a utilização do mesmo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `quick.db` usa SQLite.

Se voce abstrair razoavelmente a sua camada de DB, sim, quando vc precisar de mais escala, ficaria menos invasivo.

Agora, sobre voce criar o seu proprio `Model`, dai fica arriscado. Vc vai ter que dedicar muito tempo implementando o seu proprio.

Experimente o [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/sqlite), ele da suporte pro SQLite e tem uma boa e moderna solucao de models.

Comment: Estava dando uma lida sobre o prisma após sua recomendação e vou adotar o mesmo. Realmente seria um trabalho que levaria bastante tempo para implementar manualmente os meus próprios Models, levando em conta que terá futuramente models mais complexos. Grato pela ajuda e pelos esclarecimentos.